# "sytax error : unterminated quoted string " error when i run bash script.sh

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a situation where, I need to call a script bash c++ which is in turn called inside another bash script:

```
EPSILONS=(0.1)
INPUT="/home/garrett/dev/nearness/data/objectDescriptions"
FEATURES="18"
DISTANCE_MEASURE="sgmd"
OUTPUT_PREFIX="output_5_old_bulk"
TIME_OUTPUT=$OUTPUT_PREFIX"_time"
BIN="/home/garrett/dev/nearness/recursive/bin/nearness"
echo "$INPUT"
for e in "${EPSILONS[@]}"
do
    echo "$e"
    echo "$e" >> "$TIME_OUTPUT"  
    echo "$BIN"
    /usr/bin/time -v "$BIN" -d "$DISTANCE_MEASURE" -e "$e" -f "$FEATURES" -o "$OUTPUT_PREFIX"_e"$e" "$INPUT"
    echo
    echo >> "$TIME_OUTPUT"
    echo "Saved to $OUTPUT_PREFIX"_e"$e"
done
```

when I run bashscript.sh, below is the error I face:

> Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Comment: Check where you have unbalanced quotes.

Comment: Is this the whole script?

Comment: What does this have to do with `c++`? ... The problem looks to be the second to last line, try changing it to `echo "Saved to ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}_e${e}"`

Comment: What about the "another" script? There might be syntax error as well...

Comment: `"$OUTPUT_PREFIX"_e"$e"` is a tortuous way to express a string, but it is not incorrect, as the `_e` contains no spaces or special characters.  `"${OUTPUT_PREFIX}_e$e"` would be more readable though (the last `$e` does not need braces).